# NGINX Default Redirect for Managed Domains

Tags: nginx

I am attempting to redirect all managed domains without a server directive to a parked page located within company's domain server directive.

Currently, I have the following which will only redirect to the home page because the same directive is also needed to forward NON-TLS company domain requests.

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name   _;

    return       301 https://company.com$request_uri;
}
```

I need a server directive which will forward all requests that are not company.com to company.com/parked.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  company.com;

    return       301 https://company.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name   _;

    return 301 https://company.com/parked.php;
}
```

So, you specify a vhost for your `company.com` domain which handles the http -> https redirection, and a default server that redirects to the parking page. This is a bit more efficient than using `if` directive.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
if ( $host != 'company.com' ) {
   return 301 https://company.com/parked.php
}
```

NB: If is considered evil in nginx (https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) but this is one of the few safe ways to use it.